# What's controlling Vim paste behaviour?

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, visual-mode, mouse

What's controlling Vim paste behaviour via Vim over ssh using putty with right-click paste set to Linux host?

To start we have:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Mar 27 2023 00:00:00)
Included patches: 1-1429 on Fedora Core 37
vi -U NONE foo
: verbose set paste? mouse?
nopaste
  mouse=
```

Starting with text:

```
|---------|
|xxxiyyy  |
|replaceme|
|---------|
```

If I double-click to highlight **xxxiyyy** and do one of `viw<right-click>` or `diw<right-click>` with the vim cursor over **replaceme**, the first part works to visually select or delete but then I right-click, the full text selected is inserted. I would expect instead the first 3 characters are deleted, it goes into insert mode and then pastes 'yyy' before the string as in:

```
|---------|
|xxxiyyy  |
|yyylaceme|
|---------|
```

but instead it looks like:

```
|---------|
|xxxiyyy  |
|xxxiyyy  |
|---------|
```

It's not something I use often but in older versions of Vim, I was able to paste more macro like text and replacements. `ciw<right-click>` works of course but I would expect that.

Comment: If you expect `<right-click>` to execute the macro `xxxiyyy`, why do you visually select first?

Comment: I was trying to quickly delete and fix part of a prefix so I wasn't using visual but the question came up why does that work too when the options for mouse and paste weren't set that should have stopped this behavior.